# How to get SQLProvier to work on dotnet core 3.1 MySQL (actually MariaDB)?

Tags: f#, mariadb, mysql-connector, type-providers

I have a dotnet core 3.1 project with nuget reference to SQLProvider trying to target a MariaDB server.
I have added the community made package MySqlConnector. My F# code is

```
open FSharp.Data.Sql

[<Literal>]
let connString  = "Server=192.168.128.7;Database=market_data;Uid=****;Pwd=****;Port=3307;AllowLoadLocalInfile=true"

[<Literal>]
let dbVendor    = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MYSQL


[<Literal>]
let resPath = "__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__" + "/DLLs"

[<Literal>]
let useOptTypes = true

type sql = 
    SqlDataProvider<
        Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MYSQL,
        connString,
        ResolutionPath = resPath,
        UseOptionTypes = useOptTypes>
```

And I am getting the error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   FS3033  The type provider 'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlTypeProvider' reported an error: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
Details: 
Could not load type 'System.ICloneable' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
Could not load type 'System.Data.Common.DbCommandBuilder' from assembly 'System.Data.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
Could not load type 'System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter' from assembly 'System.Data.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
Could not load type 'System.Data.Common.RowUpdatingEventArgs' from assembly 'System.Data.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
Could not load type 'System.Data.Common.RowUpdatedEventArgs' from assembly 'System.Data.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Primitives, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Could not load type 'System.ReadOnlyMemory`1' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
Could not load type 'System.IO.Stream' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
Could not load type 'System.ReadOnlySpan`1' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Transactions.Local, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
Could not load type 'System.Memory`1' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.    Analytics   OMMITED\Program.fs  23  Active
```

I have put the files 'MySqlConnector.dll'; 'System.Data.Odbc.dll'; 'System.Data.SqlClient.dll' in the folder 'DLLs'. This is suggested as a fix from [this github issue](https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider/issues/542).

I have tried installing each assembly mentioned in the error. Can't seem to get it to work.

**EDIT**

Here is my fsproj snippet

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MySqlConnector" Version="0.61.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLProvider" Version="1.1.76" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Console" Version="4.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.Common" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection.TypeExtensions" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime" Version="4.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Extensions" Version="4.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" Version="4.5.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: You tried to use a .NET Framework library in an .NET Core application. All those libraries and versions are .NET Framework 4.x *runtime libraries*

Comment: What does your FsProj look like? What are those `MySqlConnector.dll`, `System.Data.Odbc.dll` and `System.Data.SqlClient.dll` files? Why weren't they added through NuGet?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos which one is a .NET Framework library? As for the second question, they were added through nuget, but this fix is a work around for the design time type provider to work, apparently.

Comment: *All* of those errors complain about trying to load .NET Framework libraries. That "fix" probably *caused* the problem - if you copied the .NET Framework version of System.Data.Client.dll and then tried to load it, you'd get *all* those exceptions*. The same for System.Data.Odbc.dll.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I copied those dlls from the build/bin folder, obtained after commenting out the offending f# code so it compiles and then building. So they should be .net core dlls.

Comment: In which case you have *another* .NET Framework library in there. Where did `MySqlConnector.dll` come from? *Post your fsproj* so people can reproduce the problem. You haven't even explained which NuGet packages you used. The only thing that's certain is that the code is trying to load a .NET Framework library

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have edited to include fsproj. On a related note, given a dll file only, is there any way to determine if it is for .Net framework or if it is for .Net Core?

Comment: Was you able to resolve this issue? If so what was the way to fix it?

Comment: @skiedr I was not able to resolve it. I used Dapper as a fallback. But I think the proper way to resolve it is to split SQLProvider into multiple packages specialised to each database, each with a dependency on a base package which defines the interface, and each with all required dlls included. I don’t think it is appropriate that we have to go through this song and dance to use SQLProvider with dotnet core.